# Octopus Deploy uses a snapshot of deployment until I create a new release

Tags: deployment, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to set up a deployment in Octopus Deploy. As many other devs, I do that through iterations: tweak steps/scripts/packages -> click "Deploy" -> inspect the outcome -> start again if not satisfied. In case of Octopus Deploy, it uses a snapshot of the deployment process if any steps/scripts were changed since last release. Basically, when it comes to deploy, I get this warning:

> Warning: for consistency, this deployment will use a snapshot of the variables and deployment process, which do not include the latest changes that have been made to the project. A changed process can only be incorporated by creating a new release (this one may be renamed if desired). Variables can be updated via the release page.

This means that I need to add a new release just to check if my deployment scripts change has taken effect or not. To add a release, I need to update the version and so on.

My question would be: how can I redeploy the same release with all the step changes introduced since the previous release? Is there a way to not create a new release to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked this question of Paul Stovall several months ago when I started working with Octopus.  His answer was "no".

I'm afraid there is not a way to do this without creating a new release.  When you create a release, Octopus deploy stores an object in its internal database which is a snapshot in time containing everything needed to deploy.  It doesn't have a mechanism to update these stored objects, and so it is required for you to create a new release each time.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, at least this proves that I am not the only one who ran into this thing.

Comment: I'm a perfectionist - I HATE seeing failed deploys number in the tens before the configuration gets nailed down, otherwise it wouldn't matter but for the extra time it takes to make the configuration.  I am hooked into team city, so i just hit the run button in TC and it publishes the new build for me while I get caught up on XKCD.

Comment: This is a feature that ensures deploys are reproducible. It would be wrong to start updating the snapshot because you could potentially ruin the deployment process for the earlier releases.

Comment: Just to add some information about release snapshots, there is a feature where you can 'update variables' on a release which updates this snapshot. It gives a warning but you can update a release now without needing to create a new duplicate of it just for an updated snapshot. https://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/15459-update-variables-in-a-release-via-octopusclient-or-directly-via-rest-api
I've used this myself.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that even though a snapshot of the process is taken, the *variables* can be updated if you're redeploying a previous release. If you're just changing variable values, then yes, you can reuse the same release over and over. If you're changing any of the process steps, then no - you have to create a new release.

If anything the version number just helps keep things segregated. The only time this becomes a problem is if you're using NuGet versioning, but if you're using the standard variable template versioning in Octopus deploy, it's incrementing the last digit in the version number.

Answer (score 2):

You can rename your failing release on the release page (under: Edit this release). That way you can create a new release with the old versionnumber and avoid unecessary work.